# Find a value in a range of strings

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a range with strings like this:

[image]

I want to find a cell with a specific text (the string values in range are unique). I need cell row number...

How can I do that?

Example:

```
 |  A  |  B  |  C |
1| AA1   BB1   CC1
2| AA2   BB2   CC2
3| AA3   BB3   CC3
```

- Text to search: "CC2" --> Result: 2 (row number for C2 cell)
- Text to search: "BB3" --> Result: 3 (row number for B3 cell)

Thank you very much.

Comment: Without being able to follow which string is the target or the result, I have had success with both FIND() and MATCH(). Until you improve the question....

Comment: Modified the question... I hope now is more clear. Thank you.

Comment: Have you made any efforts yourself?

Comment: The most common answer would be to use `SUMPRODUCT`, like shown [here](https://exceljet.net/formula/get-location-of-value-in-2d-array). However there are many more ways, like @SolarMike also pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

Great! I solved with this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(ROW(A1:C3)*(A1:C3="text_to_search"))-ROW(A1:C3)+1
```

Thank you!